# two bootstrap menu collapse issue on large screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have top menu and left menu on page, I want that both should collapse on small screen, these are working fine for small but on large screen both menu don't display.

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container nav-main">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#first">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" role="complementary" >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>


           <span class="navbar-brand">Business Name Test </span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse" id="first">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                  <a href="/Settings"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Settings</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="/Help"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Help</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="/Account/LogOff"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>

              </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="container main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse" id="sidebar" role="complementary" >
                    <div class="m-sidebar">

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Link1">Link1</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Link2">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Messages" rel="tooltip" title="Link3">Link3</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/Inventory" rel="tooltip" title="Link 4">Link 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="/Inventory" rel="tooltip" title="Link 4">Link 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="/Inventory" rel="tooltip" title="Link 4">Link 6</a></li>
         <li><a href="/Inventory" rel="tooltip" title="Link 4">Link 7</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-10">
        <div class="page-header">
              <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /container -->
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QWG9/5/)

Please guide me what is wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

In order to correct the position of the links, i changed the order of the navbar elements, first the left side, then the right side ( it was not the problem, its a matter of organization). Added a division between the nav & the page title. Changed the class of the navbar items on the left to :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
```

Instead of just

```
<ul class="nav">
```

Here is the Final Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FDkqT/

I know its simple, but if you expand the window you will see that it works just right